# Find $n$ numbers which LCM is equal to $k$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Is there any algorithm to find $n$ natural numbers which LCM is equal to $k$?
(There is no number that's equal to $k$.)

Comment: If you want them to be distinct natural numbers, $n$ can't be more than the number of divisors of $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I suppose that "there is no number that equal to k" should mean "find $n$ **proper** divisors of $k$".)*

As noted by Henning, you can't have more of them then the number of divisors (in $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Z$ according to your wish).

An algorithm:

- For the first two numbers, take $k/p$ and $k/q$ for two distinct primes $p,q$ that divide $k$.
- For the rest, take any divisors of $k$.

If $k$ is a power of a prime, than lcm of any of its proper divisors will be less than $k$, so you can't do it no matter what. Otherwise, you have $\operatorname{lcm}(k/p,k/q)=k$, and then adding any divisor of $k$ doesn't change this.

**Example.** Let $k=120$. It has three prime divisors, we'll choose $p=5$ and $q=3$. Then the sequence starts with $120/5=24$ and $120/3=40$ for which indeed, $\operatorname{lcm}(24,40)=120$. Then we add the other divisors in any order, obtaining for instance $$24,40,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,20,30,60.$$